# Binding stylesheet along with HTML div when converting div data into a word document

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a function which convert my HTML Div section into a word document. I have used various styles which is embedded in a css file. Although those styles are implied to HTML div at displaying those styles aren't passed to the document created afterward. How can I pass both css and the HTML div when creating the word document? Please find the function used to create the document from html div

```
function Export2Doc(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });

    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';

    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }

    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Comment: You mean you wanna include your css on the generated msword document?

Comment: can't you just include the css on the html before converting it?

Comment: I want my generated msword document to have the same styles displayed in the div

Comment: @bobharleydo you know how to include css on the html before converting it?I even tried with inline styling but its also not working

Comment: you can create a style tag containing your css and insert it on the html before converting it. have you tried that?

Comment: @bobharley can you show me an example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the converted document supports styling with css, you can inject your css code to your html before converting it like so:

```
const el = document.querySelector('#yourElement').cloneNode(true)
const style = document.createElement('style')

style.innerHTML = `
  div {
    height: 100%;
  }
` // your styles

const wrapper = document.querySelector('div') // put them inside a wrapper
wrapper.appendChild(style)
wrapper.appendChild(el)

// Then convert `wrapper`
```